# Authorizing users by downloading file from external SharePoint portal

Tags: php, security, sharepoint, authorization

I have an open question about my idea. Here's some background:
I'm developing a PHP application for the company I work in. It's meant to be used only by its employees. Every employee has access to our SharePoint portal. Basically the app has to be accessible only for people, that have access to our SharePoint.

I've got an idea to use SP to authorize users in my app. Authorization would be based on downloading a secured file from SP (one for all users), using CURL. If the file is correctly downloaded you're logged in. If it isn't, you're not allowed to access the app (there would be exception handling of course). 
So, each person, who has access to SP, would have access to the app. The app and SP are located at different servers.

What do you think about that idea? Will it be safe? Is it a good idea at all?

I've listed some pros and cons that came to my mind...

Pros:

- easy to develop
- access control is held by SharePoint
- users don't have to learn new logins and passwords
- IMO it should be safe, because no passwords would be stored in the app's database

Cons / vulnerabilities:

- possibility that the file will be accidentally deleted

Cheers,
Zibi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a good idea.  You are basically trusting the client to authenticate itself, which is very bad.  You must assume that the client code is completely compromised and has been modified by an attacker to bypass your controls.

Generally speaking, "roll-your-own" security is a recipe for disaster.  You should take advantage of PHP's built in session tracking mechanism.  You can find [a good tutorial here](http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/php/article.php/3472581/PHP-Tutorial-Sessions.htm) if you don't know how to use it yet.  Your user's will have to authenticate again, but unfortunately that is necessary for proper security.

Also keep in mind that with your suggested solution there could be no access controls beyond "employee."  This is severely limiting in the future if you ever need to provide the ability to restrict users access to resources based on user ID, roles or groups.  You'll be much happier in the future if you do it properly at this point in the game.

Comment: Thank you for your opinion, Freedom_Ben. After rethinking the whole idea, I think you are right about that. It is better to do it in a proper way.